# Ruby Sinatra App Can't Connect to Local Postgres

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra

I recently made a small wrapper in Sinatra. I had it working locally using SQLite, and I decided to switch to Postgres for the eventual move to Heroku.

However, I can't get my app to connect to my local postgres db. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.

Here is database.yml:

```
development:
    host: localhost
    adapter: postgresql
    database: postgres
    username: 
    password:
```

Here is environments.rb:

```
configure :production, :development do
db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/postgres')

 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
   :adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
   :host     => db.host,
   :username => db.user,
   :password => db.password,
   :database => db.path[1..-1],
   :encoding => 'utf8'
 )
end
```

This is the result when I try to rake:

Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.

I can connect to the db via psql and localhost just fine.

Comment: Did you add the `pg` gem to your Gemfile, commit, and push?

Comment: Yep, even did a clean bundle install locally. The db works fine on Heroku actually, but I'm trying to marry my two environments so migrating data back and forth is easier.

Comment: Aren't you missing something? (user/pass)

Comment: No, removed them for purposes of the post.